# Python Virtual Environment: changed path of enviroment - can't find packages anymore (How to show the enviroment where its packages are located)

Tags: python, django, virtualenv, filepath, directory-structure

I have a issue with my virutal enviroment and I couldn't find a clear and straightforward awnser for it. 
I had a fully working virtual enviroment with a lot of packages. My directory changed from *"../Desktop/.."* to *"../Cloud_Name/Desktop/.."* and lets assume i can't change that anymore. 
I'm now able to `cd` into my eviroment and `activate` it. 
If I now want to use any kind of command I get:

> *Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using "C: ..." "C: ..." the system cannot find the specified file.*

I tried sofar to change the directory in *"eviroment/Scripts/activate"* and *"eviroment/Scripts/activate.bat"*, but it doesn't work. 
I don't want to install a new enviroment. 
I'd be very thankfull if someone has a working solution to show my eviroment where its packages are.
Thank you in advance for your time and have a great day!

Comment: i would delete the virtualenv and recreate it in the wanted directory

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to activate your virtual environment, I suggest storing the installed packages (their names and version) into a requirements file by running `pip freeze > requirements.txt` Then recreate a new environment. After which you can reinstall your previous packages through `pip install -r requirements.txt`.

Virtualenv usually creates a symbolic link to reference package locations and I think after you changed the location of the environments, it did not (though it usually does not) update the symbolic links to the new location.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! This was helpful. My Enviroment now works. I would still love to have an answer by not reinstalling the enviroment.